# CActiveForm object does not render JS code

Tags: yii

I have a simple CFormModel subclass that is used as a form to change a password. The class has only two attributes (password1, password2 - for confirmation -). Here is the code:

```
class ChangePasswordForm extends CFormModel {

  public $password1;
  public $password2;

  public function rules() {
    return array(
      array('password1, password2', 'required'),
      array('password2', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password1'),
      array('password1, password2', 'safe'),
    );
  }

  public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
      'password1' => 'Enter new password',
      'password2' => 'Confirm new password',
    );
  }
}
```

In a controller view file, I use a CActiveForm object to render this form:

```
<?php
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm',
  array(
    'id'=>'change-pwd-form',
    'action'=>array('site/changePasswordPost'),
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
      'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
  )
);

echo $form->errorSummary($changePwdForm);
?>
<fieldset><legend>Change your password</legend>
  <div class="row">
    <?php
    echo $form->labelEx($changePwdForm, 'password1');
    echo $form->passwordField($changePwdForm, 'password1');
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <?php
    echo $form->labelEx($changePwdForm, 'password2');
    echo $form->passwordField($changePwdForm, 'password2');
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <?php
    echo CHtml::submitButton('Change password');
    ?>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<?php
$this->endWidget();
?>
```

In the controller action, I render the view above, passing a ChangePasswordForm object:

```
$changePwdForm = new ChangePasswordForm;
$this->render('changePassword', array('userid'=>$userid, 'userType'=>$t,
  'changePwdForm'=>$changePwdForm));
Yii::app()->end();
```

The problem is that while the view is rendered, no Javascript code is generated. Nothing. So clicking on the submit button, although it should not let me do it (since the two password fields are required), it does submit. What is wrong with the code above and no Javascript is created?

Comment: why are you adding the safe rule for password1 and password2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `$form->error()` for fields that you need to validate. I suppose you perform ajax validation in controller, if not - search by `performAjaxValidation` [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm)

Comment: That was it. error() was needed for each field. Thanks @mashingan.